# Writing a table to multiple files in R

Tags: r

Seemingly simple question, but I don't know how the loop syntax and variable assignments work in R very well. I have a 6900 line table that I want parsed into 10 equal sized text files. My code is below, but how would I design a loop around it and iterate through the filenames?

```
write.table(clipboard[1:619,1], 
              "mydata1.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[619:1238,1], 
              "mydata2.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[1238:1857,1], 
              "mydata3.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[1857:2476,1], 
              "mydata4.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[2476:3095,1], 
              "mydata5.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[3095:3714,1], 
              "mydata6.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[3714:4333,1], 
              "mydata7.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[4333:4952,1], 
              "mydata8.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[4952:5571,1], 
              "mydata9.txt",sep="\t")
  write.table(clipboard[5571:6190,1], 
              "mydata10.txt",sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The manual way

I guess not such an issue to use a loop for IO:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  start <- 1 + (i-1) * nrow(clipboard) / 10
  end <- i * nrow(clipboard) / 10
  fname <- paste("mydata", i ,".txt", sep="")
  write.table(x=clipboard[start:end, 1], file=fname, sep="\t")
}
```

Note that this assumes that it can actually be separated into 10 equally sized files!

### Done properly, write.split:

This method will actually (when not perfectly divisable) create an extra file for the remainder.

I used this `splitter` to create a list of data that will then be used in parallel for some statistical computations in my package `correlate`. Here, it actually means we would be able to write the files in parallel. Note that this is pointless for small files; maybe even slower.

```
# Helper to split the data in chunks
splitter <- function(x, splitsize) {
  nr <- nrow(x)
  if (splitsize > nr) {
    splitsize <- nr
  }
  splits <- floor(nr / splitsize)
  splitted.list <- lapply(split(x[seq_len(splits*splitsize), ],
                          seq_len(splits)), function(x) matrix(x, splitsize))
  if (nr %% splitsize != 0) {
    splitted.list$last <- x[(splits * splitsize + 1):nr, ]
  }
  return(splitted.list)
}

write.split <- function(x, chunks, file.prefix, file.extension, cores = 1, ...) {
  splitsize <- nrow(x) / chunks
  splitted.list <- splitter(x, splitsize)
  if (cores == 1) {
    sapply(names(splitted.list), function(z) 
           write.table(splitted.list[z],
                       file = paste(file.prefix, z, file.extension, sep=""),
                       ...))
  } else {
    # currently just the simple linux version; this won't work on Windows.
    # Upon request I'll add it
    stopifnot(require(parallel))
    mclapply(names(splitted.list), function(z) 
           write.table(splitted.list[z],
                       file = paste(file.prefix, z, file.extension, sep=""),
                       ...))
  }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
write.split(z, chunks = 10,
            file.prefix = "mydata", file.extension = ".txt", sep="\t")
```

You can also give it the `row.names` and `col.names` arguments, basically anything that can be passed to `write.table`.

**Benchmark**:

```
Using `matrix(1:1000000, 1000)` as data.
Unit: seconds
   expr         min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 1-core    1.780022 1.990751 2.079907 2.166891 2.744904   100 
4-cores    1.305048 1.438777 1.492114 1.559110 2.070911   100
```

**Extensibility**: 
It could also be easily extended by allowing to give a number of lines to write rather than the amount of chunks.